# Angular 2 Shared Data Service is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, observable, angular-services

I have built a shared data service that's designed to hold the users login details which can then be used to display the username on the header, but I cant get it to work.

Here's my (abbreviated) code:

```
// Shared Service
@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

    // Observable string source
    private dataSource = new Subject<any>();

    // Observable string stream
    data$ = this.dataSource.asObservable();

    // Service message commands
    insertData(data: Object) {
        this.dataSource.next(data)
    }
}
```

...

```
// Login component
import { SharedDataService } from 'shared-data.service';
@Component({
    providers: [SharedDataService]
})
export class loginComponent {
    constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) {}

    onLoginSubmit() {
        // Login stuff
        this.authService.login(loginInfo).subscribe(data => {
             this.sharedData.insertData({'name':'TEST'});
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
// Header component
import { SharedDataService } from 'shared-data.service';
@Component({
    providers: [SharedDataService]
})
export class headerComponent implements OnInit {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sharedData.data$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('onInit',data)
            this.greeting = data.name
        });
    }
}
```

I can add a console log in the service insertData() method which shoes the model being updated, but the OnInit method doesn't reflect the change.

The code I've written is very much inspired by this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/neM6EdYYUkGkRpF0fKGS?p=preview) which does work, so I am at a loss as to what's wrong.

Before posting here I tried a few other attempts. [This one](https://plnkr.co/edit/EjxffJLwTAusMI6BtEUw?p=preview) and [this one](https://plnkr.co/edit/neM6EdYYUkGkRpF0fKGS?p=preview) again both work on the demo, but not in my app.

I'm using Angular 2.4.8.

Looking through different tutorials and forum posts all show similar examples of how to get a shared service working, so I guess I am doing something wrong. I'm fairly new to building with Angular 2 coming from an AngularJS background and this is the first thing that has me truly stuck.

Thanks

Comment: if you put your service as a **provider** in any component, the **constructor** will be called each time. You probably want to have a unique instance of the entire service in your entire application. To accomplish such, either inject the provider in the **NgModule providers** (in your app module), either inject the provider in the parent view and add it to **viewProviders**. In your case, though, it would be better to directly inject the service in the **AppModule**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a recurring problem in understanding Angular's dependency injection.

The basic issue is in how you are configuring the providers of your service.

**The short version:**
Always configure your providers at the NgModule level **UNLESS** you want a separate instance for a specific component. Only then do you add it to the providers array of the component that you want the separate instance of.

**The long version:**
Angular's new dependency injection system allows for you to have multiple instances of services if you so which (which is in contrast to AngularJS i.e. Angular 1 which ONLY allowed singletons). If you configure the provider for your service at the NgModule level, you'll get a singleton of your service that is shared by all components/services etc. But, if you configure a component to also have a provider, then that component (and all its subcomponents) will get a different instance of the service that they can all share. This option allows for some powerful options if you so require.

That's the basic model. It, is of course, not quite so simple, but that basic rule of configuring your providers at the NgModule level by default unless you explicitly want a different instance for a specific component will carry you far.

And when you want to dive deeper, [check out the official Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html)

Also note that lazy loading complicates this basic rule as well, so again, check the docs.

**EDIT:**

So for your specific situation,

```
@Component({
    providers: [SharedDataService]  <--- remove this line from both of your components, and add that line to your NgModule configuration instead
})
```

Comment: Thanks bougarfaoui-el-houcine, snorkpete and briosheje. Within quarter of an hour there's three excellent answers. Thanks all for your help. I misunderstood the providers thing, you've cleared it up.

Answer (score 3):

Add it in @NgModule.providers array of your `AppModule`:

if you add it in @Component.providers array then you are limiting the scope of `SharedDataService` instance to that component and its children.

in other words each component has its own injector which means that `headerComponent`will make its own instance of `SharedDataService`and `loginComponent` will make its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

My case is that I forget to configure my imports to add HttpClientModule in @NgModules, it works.